# What is a Direct X Virtual Table?

Tags: c++, directx

I have a question about virtual table.

The virtual table as i know is the function address arrays which can find
the function address when the polymorphism object call virtual function.

But In directx, some people mentioned about dx vtable that the table of d3d9.dll
's import function address arrays.

Why they call the import function address arrays to directx vtable?
It seems to not relevant with a vtable.

Did My knowledge was incorrect? May i know about vtable in detail? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When exporting COM objects from a DLL, there are usually two parts at work. First is the 'factory'. The factory can be a standard C-callable function exported from the DLL (which is the case with Direct3D), or a class registered with the system registry in which case you'd use `CoCreateInstance` to create the COM interface instance. An example of the first is creating a Direct3D device:

```
ID3D11Device* d3dDevice = nullptr;

hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
    nullptr,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    0,
    0,
    nullptr,
    0,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &d3dDevice,
    nullptr,
    nullptr);
```

After this call, the `d3dDevice` interface points to an allocated COM interface object. The DLL that contains `D3D11CreateDevice` has to be implicitly linked to the calling program--or you can use `LoadLibrary` to do explicitly linking in which case you'd use a pointer to the function `D3D11CreateDevice` which amounts to much the same thing . This is derived from the 'import table' for the DLL.

An example of the second is what you do when using Windows Imaging Component (WIC):

```
IWICImagingFactory* factory = nullptr;
hr = CoCreateInstance(
         CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
         nullptr,
         CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
         __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory),
         &factory);
```

This has the COM system look up the class GUID in the registry, load up the referenced DLL, and then invoke the factory methods in there to create a COM interface object which it returns to you.

In both cases, the actual thing pointed to by the interface is of the form:

```
typedef struct IUnknownVtbl
{
    BEGIN_INTERFACE

    HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *QueryInterface )( 
        IUnknown * This,
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [annotation][iid_is][out] */ 
        _COM_Outptr_  void **ppvObject);

    ULONG ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *AddRef )( 
        IUnknown * This);

    ULONG ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *Release )( 
        IUnknown * This);

    END_INTERFACE
} IUnknownVtbl;
```

which is contrived to *exactly* map to the Visual C++ implementation of `virtual`:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
IUnknown
{
public:
    BEGIN_INTERFACE
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface( 
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [annotation][iid_is][out] */ 
        _COM_Outptr_  void **ppvObject) = 0;

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef( void) = 0;

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release( void) = 0;

    END_INTERFACE
};
```

COM doesn't really have a notion of inheritance, but again it's a convenience for `ID3D11Device1` to use C++ public inheritance from `ID3D1Device` which only works because the language type has no data members declared. COM "inheritance" of interfaces is really just concatenation of the methods which you can see if you look at the C definitions in the headers:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(CINTERFACE)

    MIDL_INTERFACE("cc86fabe-da55-401d-85e7-e3c9de2877e9")
    ID3D11BlendState1 : public ID3D11BlendState
    {
    public:
        virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetDesc1( 
            /* [annotation] */ 
            _Out_  D3D11_BLEND_DESC1 *pDesc) = 0;

    };


#else   /* C style interface */

    typedef struct ID3D11BlendState1Vtbl
    {
        BEGIN_INTERFACE

        HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *QueryInterface )(  /* ... */ );

        ULONG ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *AddRef )( ID3D11BlendState1 * This);

        ULONG ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *Release )( ID3D11BlendState1 * This);

        void ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *GetDevice )(  /* ... */ );

        HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *GetPrivateData )(  /* ... */ );

        HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *SetPrivateData )(  /* ... */ );

        HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *SetPrivateDataInterface )(  /* ... */ );

        void ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *GetDesc )( 
            ID3D11BlendState1 * This,
            /* [annotation] */ 
            _Out_  D3D11_BLEND_DESC *pDesc);

        void ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *GetDesc1 )( 
            ID3D11BlendState1 * This,
            /* [annotation] */ 
            _Out_  D3D11_BLEND_DESC1 *pDesc);

        END_INTERFACE
    } ID3D11BlendState1Vtbl;

#endif
```

> It's important to note this only works for the case of pure virtual (i.e. abstract) C++ classes with no data members and only virtual methods using public inheritance (i.e. interfaces). Constructors and destructors are ignored as COM life-time is managed through reference-counting via `IUnknown`.

The calling signatures of methods also take a pointer to the COM object as the first parameter which maps to the C++ calling convention for `this`.

**COM interfaces are therefore designed to work like C++ virtual methods so you can use C++ syntax to call them, but they aren't necessarily C++ class objects at all.**

From `IUnknown` there is a known standard way in COM to get a specific interface, which is `QueryInterface`. The Direct3D factory functions take care of this for you as well, and just return the base interface. In the case of Direct3D 11, that's a `ID3D11Device`.

> If you want to get an interface to say 11.1, you then use `QueryInterface` on the `ID3D11Device` asking for a `ID3D11Device1`. It would fail on a DirectX 11.0 system, but works on a DirectX 11.1 or later system.

For a C++ programmer using Direct3D, the design purposely keeps the "COM" to a minimum (colloquially known as "COM lite"). Really just enough COM is used to make it easier to deal with interface changes over time and to provide a reasonable ABI. The Direct3D factory functions are simple C-callable exports from a known DLL, so you don't even have to muck about with the standard COM factories and in fact the API isn't designed to work if you try to use `CoCreateInstance`. You can technically use C via some macros that the standard [MIDL compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367091.aspx) generates along with the C++ definitions, but it's a bit challenging to do and isn't particularly well tested these days.

Really all you need to know as a consumer of Direct3D COM is the basics of `IUnknown` reference counting and querying--which today is best done by using the [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) smart-pointer--and how to properly check `HRESULT` values--see [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).

> See [The Component Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx) and [Reference Counting (Direct3D 10)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205070.aspx)

Comment: What a great detailed answer! I would just like to add the clarification that COM and c++ objects are nothing alike. A d3d12 interface does not override a d3d9 interface. There is no inheritance. Both have their own "vtable" of functions, but there is no relation between them, no common ancestor. You can not cast a d312 object to d3d9.

Comment: Excellent point. I updated to cover this point... They are not in fact alike, but the COM interface design is contrived to make it possible to rely on C++ calling syntax to make them _appear_ to be pure virtual classes with public inheritance.